# The turning moment diagram of engine

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, torque

In the engine, how is the force in the connecting rod Fg/cos(phi) ,  when the piston is not in static condition, but is rather moving forward? (https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0Bxi.png)

Comment: side-note -> Objects in equilibrium are not necessarily at rest.

Comment: Where did you get the image and in what context was it presented.

Answer (score 1):

I looked up the source of your link to determine the context of the diagram. I quote the following:

*“For the purpose of gas torque analysis, let us **assume** for the time being that all of the links have **negligible mass and ignore any inertia force effects**. Of course some of the the gas torque will have to be used to overcome the inertia of the moving parts. From the free body diagram shown in Fig 5.2 and the considerations of static equilibrium, we find the normal force on the cylinder frame at the piston is given by:”*

I have bold faced the portions of the statement relevant to answer your question. It is assumed that although the piston is “moving” (not static) they are ignoring the torque to overcome the inertia of the moving parts, in particular, the piston. In other words, the piston is not accelerating and is always moving with constant speed. This means that the net horizontal force on the piston is always zero. Or, horizontal component of the force in the connecting rod will always equal $F_{g}$

$$\frac{F_{g}}{cos Φ}cosΦ=F_{g}$$

In reality this is not, of course, the case. The piston has mass and needs to decelerate as it approaches the extremes to bring it to a stop and reverse direction and then accelerates. That requires a net horizontal force to act on the piston during the cycle.

I have attached a diagram below (which was used to discuss flywheels).  Figures 1 and 5 show the situation where the piston is about to reverse direction and the net horizontal force is zero. Figure 4 roughly represents the position in you link. Given the direction of flywheel rotation shown, the piston is decelerating.  The piston is Figure 6 shows the same but with the piston direction reversed. The piston is accelerating. Clearly if the piston has mass, there needs to be a net horizontal force.

Hope this helps.
[image]

Comment: Actually, this was truly helpful and thanks. The textbooks rarely describe in detail, and simplify some things, which leads to confusion. The actual formulas would be more complex I guess.

Answer (score 0):

The diagram and the force component $F_g/\cos\phi$ assumes all inertial effects are negligible. You can see this because the mass and mass moment of inertia of the connecting rod and the mass of the piston do not enter into consideration.

Additionally, the actual vehicle inertial forces are far lesser than the internal forces. In a modern car, the engine spins every 0.01 seconds, where a car changes speed by 0.1 meters per second at 1 gee of acceleration, compared to the speed of the reciprocating components of 20 meters per second. For all practical purposes, a car is an inertial frame of reference when it comes to engine analysis.